# Dynamically passing a class as a parameter and its method - php

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, oop

I have a class `First` and `Second`

```
class First{

//methods

}

class Second{

//methods

}
```

Another class named `Third`

I need to send those class names dynamically as a parameter to `Third` class method and load it like below.

```
class Third{

    function getData($id, $dynamicClass){  // class names first or second as a parameter
        $this->load->model($dynamicClass);
        $id = $this->$dynamicClass->insert($data);
        return $id; 
    }

}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried to access to property with braces notation `$id = $this->{$dynamicClass}->insert($data);` ?

Comment: So how does `$this->$dynamicClass` get magically an instance of the class your passing by calling `$this->load->model($dynamicClass)`?

Comment: @dbf : it seems that the OP is using CodeIgniter

Comment: @huggilou if that assumption is true and that's something CodeIgniter offers then I would kick the hell out of it ..

Comment: Yes using Codeigniter

Comment: @huggilou should i use like this `{$dynamicClass}` for loading the class too?

Comment: @SO-user No your dynamic model loading seems to be good

Comment: @huggilou That's working. Put that as answer. Ill mark as answer

Comment: @SO-user It's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to your new loaded model using this notation :

```
$this->load->model($dynamicClass);
$id = $this->{$dynamicClass}->insert($data);
```